# What's wrong with my code (PHP command-line parse error)?

Tags: php, terminal

```
<?php

/*
Xbox Live Gamertag Checker
Written by Sedulous
*/

if ($argc < 2) 
{
    print "Usage: php $argv[0] <input file> <output file>\n";
    exit;
}

$input_fd = fopen($argv[1], 'r');
$output_fd = fopen($argv[2], 'w');

while (!feof($input_fd)) 
{
    $current_gamertag = fread($input_fd, filesize($input_fd));
    $current_test_page = file_get_contents("https://live.xbox.com/en-US/Profile?gamertag=" + $current_gamertag);
    if (strpos($current_test_page, "Ooops! What happened to this page?" !== false))
    {
        fwrite($output_fd, $current_gamertag, strlen($current_gamertag));
    {
}

fclose($input_fd);
fclose($output_fd);

?>
```

This script is meant to be ran in the command-line/terminal for various reasons.

Whenever I try to run it, I get the following error: 
`"PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/jared/Desktop/gamertag_checker.php on line 31"`

I don't see any errors, does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: That means parentheses or braces don't match. Your IDE should help you find the mismatch.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
if (strpos($current_test_page, "Ooops! What happened to this page?" !== false))
    {
        fwrite($output_fd, $current_gamertag, strlen($current_gamertag));
    {
```

to

```
if (strpos($current_test_page, "Ooops! What happened to this page?" !== false))
    {
        fwrite($output_fd, $current_gamertag, strlen($current_gamertag));
    }
```

Comment: I see no difference between the original and "fixed" versions?

Comment: In original { was added in after the if .. which should be }

Answer (score 2):

```
if (strpos($current_test_page, "Ooops! What happened to this page?" !== false))
{
    fwrite($output_fd, $current_gamertag, strlen($current_gamertag));
{
```

That last one is supposed to be a }. What do you use for programming? I suggest a proper editor, NetBeans. Or, if you want something more simple, go with Notepad++ or Sublime Text 2 or 3.

Comment: @Sedulous,if you knew why you post question here?

Comment: He didn't know where it was, but he could have guessed it was a simple one. As a lot of errors usually are. Silly mistakes overlooked upon so easily.

Answer (score 0):

your strpos call is wrong:

```
yours:     if (strpos($current_test_page, "Ooops! What happened to this page?" !== false))
should be: if (strpos($current_test_page, "Ooops! What happened to this page?") !== false)
                                                                              ^---here
```

Note the location change of the `)` at the end. You're doing a strpos against the boolean true/false result of the `"Oops" is strictly not false" comparison, instead of a "result of strpos is not strictly false".

This is also wrong:

```
$current_test_page = file_get_contents("[..snip..]Profile?gamertag=" + $current_gamertag);
                                                                     ^---
```

`+` in PHP is mathematical addition. You want `.`, which is string concatenation.